# How to download PDF files from a list of URLs in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a big list of links to PDF files that I need to download (500+) and I was trying to make a program to download them all because I don't want to manually do them.

This is what I have and when I try to run it, the console just opens up and closes.

```py
import wget

def main():
    f = open("list.txt", "r")

    f1 = f.readlines()
    for x in f1:
        wget.download(x, 'C:/Users/ALEXJ/OneDrive/Desktop/Books')
        print("Downloaded" + x)
```

Comment: It is because you just defined the function `main()` and you are not calling it anywhere else. Add a last line just with `main()` (no indentation) and it will probably work as expected.

Comment: Ok, so I did that and it works, but now I get this error: Now I'm getting an error saying OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.\\Githubflow-Online.pdf\n1h2w2key.tmp' When the first link is https://please.dont-hack.me/books/hacking/Githubflow-Online.pdf @accdias

Comment: Replace `x` with `x.strip()` when passing it to `wget.download()`.

Comment: Thanks @accdias now I am getthing this error though "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" How could I fix that?

Comment: @AlexS. Please add all that information to your post.

Comment: @AlexS. What do/don’t you understand from that HTTPError 403? Have you given it any thought, done any research?

Comment: Also, I’m voting to close this as typo/can’t be reproduced, since the issue was that you weren’t actually calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the function `main()` but you are not calling it anywhere else.

Here is a complete example to achieve what you want:

```py
import wget


def main():
    books_folder = 'C:/Users/ALEXJ/OneDrive/Desktop/Books'
    books_list = 'list.txt'

    with open(books_list) as books:
        for book in books:
            wget.download(book.strip(), books_folder)
            print('Downloaded', book)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was working but then i got the error "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" How could I fix that?

Comment: That is nothing that is under your control. It is the site you are trying to download the books from that is denying the requests. Maybe the URLs in the `list.txt` are incorrect or you have reached some limit on the source site.

Comment: @AlexS.: you could have looked it up to find that [`404`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means that you are *not allowed* to access the URL. If you theoretically are allowed to access it (say, it's your school's site) it might require login prior to downloading. How to do that should be findable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the function call at the end of your script, is good practice to use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the code of code you want to execute (although is not mandatory it will help so if you import this file into another your code will not get executed without your knowledge)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to figure out why I'm getthing the error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.\\Githubflow-Online.pdf\n1h2w2key.tmp'" When the first link is please.dont-hack.me/books/hacking/Githubflow-Online.pdf